# new imagick does not work

Tags: php, image, imagick

I have set up the environment and configuration for the imagick in local server Xampp. it works well when I user exec like:

```
exec("convert source.jpg des.png");
```

then I want to do it in OOP way, so I attempt this with:

```
$image=new Imagick("filepath");
$image->setImageFormat('png');
echo $image;
```

but this ends up with a page saying "the web page is not available",
then I try to remove the filepath and just try to create an empty object like:

```
$image=new Imagick();
```

and this does not appear any errors. does any body know what may be the reason? one of posts in here mentioned to look at the log, but I don't know where the log is, can somebody be kind to help me? thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you passing "filepath" as a string (i.e. an image called "filepath")?
Try to turn on all PHP warnings

Comment: yes,,the path should be a string,if im right,,,could u please tell me where to turn on php warnings??